# default value for the function python

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand this question and answers:

[python function default parameter is evaluated only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087344/python-function-default-parameter-is-evaluated-only-once)

in order to understand it i try:

```
def f1(a, L=[]):
    if not L:
        print "L is empty"
        L = []
    L.append(a)
    return L

>>>f1(1)
L is empty
[1]
>>>f1(1)
L is empty
[1]

def f2(a, L=[]):
        if L:
            print "L isn't empty"
            L = []
        L.append(a)
        return L

>>>f2(1)
[1]
>>>f2(1)
L isn't empty
[1]
```

So I think in the case of `f1` `L` is becoming empty again every time - it is assigned to `[]` again after every call of `f1`. But in case of `f2` `L` is somehow isn't empty? Why?

Comment: Perhaps you can make L a global list?

Comment: I can, but don't want. All I want is to understand why is behavior of this functions is so strange

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this:

```
L = []
```

...you don't change the value referenced by `L`; you change the *reference* `L` to point to a brand new list `[]`.

If you want to empty the list referenced by `L` without changing the reference itself, you can write:

```
del L[:]
```

...or use methods such as `remove` or `pop` that work by changing the current list.

---

Here's f1 and f2 in animated form to help you understand. (Click for webm. Wait for each gif to fade to white. The gifs don't sync up, sorry.)

[image: f1]

[image: f2]

Comment: Can you explain why in case of `f2` i've got non empty list, but in case of `f1` it's always emplty though code in both functions is similar?

Comment: @user3572950 in `f1(x)`, `L=[]`, thus you run the `if not L` branch, which discards the `L` reference, so next time you run `f1(y)`, it'll still start with `L=[]`. When you call `f2(x)` the first time, `L=[]`, so you skip the `if L` branch and go straight to changing `L` with `L.append`. When you then call `f2(y)`, `L=[x]`, so you go through the `if L` branch (and discard the `L` reference).

Comment: @user yep, that's it: when you assign to L you assign a new value to the reference L without affecting the previous value. Consider this: `A=B=[]; A.append(0); print A, B; A=[]; A.append(1); B.append(2); print A, B;` this should give `[0] [0]` `[1] [0, 2]`

Comment: Maybe I'm starting to understand - there are two "versions" of `L` in each function - one "version" is default variable, evaluated only once, and other "version" - new list, that i'm creating inside `if` statement as you said **you change the reference L to point to a brand new list []**
But it's unclear to me why
 **So next time you run f1(y), it'll still start with L=[]**
By this time, when i run `f1` second time there are two "versions" of L - one is equal `[]` and another is equal `[1]` , so how can `if` statement understand what "version" of `L` it should use?

Comment: @gr4k [Maybe a moving picture is worth a thousand words. (Fixed 2)](https://gfycat.com/PlasticCooperativeBubblefish)

Comment: @gr4k [Here's `f2` as well for completeness and clarity.](https://gfycat.com/RapidKindKomododragon)